# Illumination Equalization

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to implement the illumination equalization using Matlab. I saw this link. [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292726/how-to-correct-uneven-illumination-in-images-using-matlab)!

I applied Gaussian Blur on the V channel of the HSV image. next step asks me to calculate global average V value for an image? How to do this?

This is my code till now.

```
I = imread('image2.jpg');
hsv_image = rgb2hsv(I);
im_hue = hsv_image(:,:,1)
G = fspecial('gaussian',[5,5],10);
```

G gives me an array of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
im_filter=imfilter(im_hue,G,'replicate');
V=mean(im_filter(:));
```

Comment: This is what I need to do next? 
im_hue = im_hue - G + V;
imshow(im_hue);

Comment: @wannaC after you get the average V value, just use imshow(im_filter - V)  Thx

Comment: Displays a completely black image. 
I changed the dimensions of G and then did this im_hue = im_hue - G; 
im_hue = im_hue + V;
I got an image but it was black and white.

Comment: Now I tried it. Displays a blueish image. Should I modify the sigma value?

Comment: Yes please have a try. Besides, does imahow(im_hue) display a proper image for you?

Comment: Throws an error "Undefined function or method 'imahow' for input arguments of type 'double'."

Comment: I want to perform illumination equalization on the green channel of the image.

Comment: I tried this: 
V=mean(im_filter(:));
imshow(im_hue)
Shows a black and white image.